# gobject.timeout_add not working in nose tests

Tags: python, timer, nose, gobject

I've added a module to mopidy core that uses gobject.timeout_add() for a repeating function. It works fine when running normally, however when running tests it appears that the handler function never gets called.

The module under test has a method that starts a regular process that emits events roughly every half a second. The test calls the method, then call time.sleep(2). The events from the timer function don't occur, and neither does some debug logging in the timer function. Other events and debug logging (outside the timer function) work fine.

What do I need to do to get gobject.timeout_add() to work in nose tests? Or do I need to use something other than time.sleep() in the test in order to allow the other code to run? It's calling gobject.threads_init() in the test setup, is there anything else I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

You need to be running [an event loop](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html).  As the documentation for [g_timeout_add](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-timeout-add) explains, that function (and other similar functions in glib) will [create a new timeout source](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-timeout-source-new) which is then attached to the event loop (well, the `GMainContext`, but you don't really need to worry about that).  It is *not* the equivalent of spawning a new thread and having it sleep for whatever you specified as the duration of the timeout, which seems to be the behavior you're expecting—using the main loop allows everything to happen in a single thread.

Comment: OK, thanks. It's not gtk+ though (the doco I was looking at is [here](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2reference/gobject-functions.html#function-gobject--timeout-add), it's a backend module.

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean to post that, wasn't finished typing...

I initially wrote it using a dedicated thread but someone suggested using timeout_add() instead. I've added stuff to initialise the main loop, hasn't helped though.

As far as I can tell time.sleep() is sleeping the entire main thread, which is why the timeout function never gets called. How do people write tests that test actions performed using timeout_add()? What else can I use to pause the test execution without pausing the whole thread?

Comment: time.sleep() will block whatever thread it was called in.  The main loop doesn't spawn a thread to do its stuff in—it does it in the thread you call it from.  You have to actually *run* the main loop.  Once your timeout is run you can quit the main loop (g_main_loop_quit, or whatever it is called in python) and control will return to your code right after where you called g_main_loop_run.

Comment: OK, tried various ways of mocking it, in the end the easiest way was to get the context for the main loop and call context.iterate(False) in a while loop. This lets the timeout source do its thing and the code gets executed in its entirety.